# SQL Server partition by or any other techniques

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server-2012

In SQL Server 2012:

```
ID      RANK
5400      1
5400      1
5400      1
2587      2
2587      2
1200      3
1200      3
1200      3
1200      3
```

I need to generate last column like this, as these data will be are order by date and now I want to distinct ID as in the order they are.

Without this `RANK` column I can not do it, I think so because when I distinct on ID column its internally order it by ID ascending

Note: my ID column is primary key

Expected result set :

```
5400
2587
1200
```

Current result set :

```
1200
2587
5400
```

Comment: If your `id` column is `Primary key` then how your `Id` column has duplicates

Comment: @Fireblade : hello !! as i have shown here is a result set of my SP , and i have parent child grid (three level grid) for my page , so here is a duplicate for that parent ID for their child data

Comment: You can do `select distinct id from table order by rank`

Comment: @Nairaj Ahmad : hello !! RANK column is not generated , we have to create this column like this , that is the question ...... how to create RANK column as i shown above ?

Comment: OK than can u do this `select distinct id from table order by id desc` ?

Comment: @Mairaj : my friend that is the problem , when we do like that it will order records by ID column ,,,,,we need records as it is which are with RANK column but distinct,,,read my question once again :)

Comment: You mention dates but there's none evident in the samples you're providing. You need to be aware that tables have **no** inherent order. The only way to control the *order* of rows in a result set is to have an `ORDER BY` clause on *that* query. And that, in turn, needs one or more columns (to either use directly or to use in expressions) to *define* the order.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to select a distinct list of ID then I would suggest :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TABLENAME
```

Otherwise, if you wish to add another column and set it to identity you can use the following code.
Please note that I have created #Temp1 in order to mimic your data and have create #Temp2 to import a DISTINCT list of ID's and RANK, then updated #Temp1 using the identity set on #Temp2 :

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp1 (ID INT)
INSERT INTO #Temp1 (ID)
VALUES ('5400'),
        ('5400'),
        ('5400'),
        ('2587'),
        ('2587'),
        ('1200'),
        ('1200'),
        ('1200'),
        ('1200')
ALTER TABLE #Temp1 ADD RANK INT

CREATE TABLE #Temp2 (ID INT, RANK int IDENTITY(1, 1))
INSERT INTO #Temp2 (ID)
    SELECT DISTINCT ID
    FROM #Temp1
    ORDER BY ID DESC

UPDATE #Temp1 
SET #Temp1.RANK = #Temp2.RANK 
FROM #Temp1
INNER JOIN #Temp2
       ON #Temp1.ID = #Temp2.ID  

SELECT DISTINCT RANK, ID 
FROM #Temp1

DROP TABLE #Temp1
DROP TABLE #Temp2
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello @PKirby , just insert 3000 below 1200 and then check your answer it will not remain same order as they are !!
CREATE TABLE #Temp1 (ID INT)
INSERT INTO #Temp1 (ID)
VALUES ('5400'),
        ('5400'),
        ('5400'),
        ('2587'),
        ('2587'),
        ('1200'),
        ('1200'),
        ('1200'),
        ('1200'),('3000'),('3000') ,,,,,check now

Comment: @KashyapVyas - what you've defined there is a table. It contains 4 rows with an `ID` of 1200, 3 rows with an `ID` of 5400, 2 rows with an `ID` of 3000 and 2 rows with an `ID` of 2587. There's no *inherent* ordering within a table.

Comment: @KashyapVyas - I have ran the script with 3000 included, as requested. The result will set the RANK then as 5400 (1), 3000 (2), 2587 (3), 1200 (4) -- as was requested.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is very unclear what you are asking.
Your expected result set is without a rank column.
Why do you want to have a row_number/dense_rank in the first place ? 
You only group it by id, and sort it descending by id...
That needs no rank, and not a distinct either, that goes like this:

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE_NAME 
GROUP BY ID 
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Furthermore, you claim your ID column is primary key, but it has duplicates, which means it is not a primary key because primary-keys are by definition unique-keys.

My conclusion is that you input set is the table with the id as primary-key joined with some other table(s) in either a stored procedure or a table-valued-function, and that you don't know that "group by" exists, and that you don't know that you can specify the sort direction by specifying the ASC/DESC keyword.

By the way, if you need any more values than ID, you either need to put them into the group by, or you need to use an aggregate function, e.g.

```
SELECT ID, Product_Name, MAX(Price) FROM TABLE_NAME 
GROUP BY ID, Product_Name 
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

And be careful if you use dense_rank in some way, because this will have the effect of counting a NULL value as a distinct value. Example:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
              SELECT 1 AS Id 
    UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS Id 
    UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS Id 
    UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS Id 
    UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS Id 
    UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS Id 
    UNION ALL SELECT 4 AS Id 
    UNION ALL SELECT 5 AS Id 
    UNION ALL SELECT NULL AS Id 
)

SELECT 
     Id
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS rank
FROM CTE 

ORDER BY rank DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check below answer.

```
declare @Temp table (id1 bigint identity(1, 1), Type int)

insert into @Temp
select 5400  union all
select 5400  union all
select 4500  union all
select 4500  union all
select 1800  union all
select 3200  union all
select 1800  union all
select 200  union all
select 3200
```

Now below is your query for get the rank.

```
select 
DENSE_RANK()OVER(ORDER BY Type DESC) AS 'RANKNumber', Type from @Temp
group by Type
```